# Custom section in App.Config: How to realize this structure in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, app-config, custom-sections

I have created a custom configuration section for my `App.Config` file, right now it looks like this:

```
<mySection>
  <myCollection>
    <element name="1" />
    <element name="2" />
  </myCollection>
</mySection>
```

As the naming suggests, I have classes inherited from `ConfigurationSection` (`MySection`), `ConfigurationElementCollection` (`MyCollection` with `AddItemName="element"` set in the attributes of `MySection`), and `ConfigurationElement`. But I wonder how I can realize a structure similar to the following:

```
<mySection>
  <myElements>
    <element name="1" />
    <element name="2" />
    <additionalInfo>"..."</additionalInfo>
  </myElements>
  <someOtherSetting option="blub" />
</mySection>
```

Can I still use `ConfigurationElementCollection` for `MyElements` or do I have to use something else, as there is not just the `element` tag (specified by `AddItemName="element"` in the `MySection` class), but also another one? If not, what is the class to use here?

And I guess having something between the tags has to just correspond to a property of some `AdditionalInfo` class, so that it'd be equivalent to the following?

```
<additionalInfo content="..." />
```

As for `someOtherSetting` I guess I could just add another property to `MySection` corresponding to this, but I didn't get to testing that yet.

Comment: I don't know if such a structure can be realized with `ConfigurationSection`. If not, you could try `IConfigurationSectionHandler ` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). With this you could read your config section by a xml deserialization using `XmlDeserializer`, where such structures are no problem.